# What's the best way to have a charm control Juju?

Tags: juju

Is it possible to a charm to ask juju to start another machine, add instances of a service or destroy instances? For instance, by doing something simular to the juju gui: how juju gui performs the creation of machines, for instance? I´d to have a service that monitors other services and add instances to scale out, for instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few ways this is possible.

## Installing and calling Juju binaries

The charms.reactive layer at https://github.com/galgalesh/juju-client does this. The basic process is to first bootstrap the environment, then deploy a charm passing in all the configuration, state and secrets files necessary to control the environment. The charm installs the juju client, rebuilds ~/.juju, and can now control the environment from the inside.

This layer is still experimental. If you encounter any issues, file a bug report in the github repo.

## Using the Python Juju client

There is a [Python client to manage Juju environments](https://python-jujuclient.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). This client calls the Juju api. You could put this in a Charm.

## Using the Go API

You can find the go api here: https://godoc.org/github.com/juju/juju/api

## Using Perl bindings

If you're into that sort of stuff: https://metacpan.org/release/Juju

## Calling the api directly

For more information on that, see this question: [Is there a Juju REST API?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/693689/is-there-a-juju-rest-api)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting my layer! I added some more options and a disclaimer.